# Почему input.value не меняется второй раз

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Делаю свой input, ввожу в него данные и он сразу их заменяет на "11.11", так у меня и должно быть. Но если после этой замены я продолжаю вводить данные, он перестаёт их заменять, этого я не понимаю.

У меня стоит  `v-bind:value="val"` и по идее если я перезаписываю `this.val` он должен это отображать в инпуте. Сам `val` меняется, я его выводу, но не в инпуте.

```js
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: `<span>
      <input
        v-bind:value="val"
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"> val: {{val}}
    </span>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      val: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue: function(value) {
      this.val = "11.11";
    }
  }
});

// создание корневого экземпляра
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>
                    <currency-input></currency-input>
                    </div>`,

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `v-bind:value` на `v-model`.

Comment: @RinaShmeleva так может и будет работать, но я хочу разобраться где в этом коде ошибка, и почему не работает

Comment: Сейчас оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Нет, почему не работает, я не объясню :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что vue при привязке данных использует отслеживание зависимостей и меняет только то, что изменилось.

Когда вы одному и тому же свойству `val` раз за разом присваиваете одно и то же значение - оно не меняется, а потому не вызывает обновления биндингов.

Привязку данных следует применять только в тех случаях когда есть лишь один источник изменений в один момент времени, а не когда два источника данных (вы и пользователь) "дерутся" за одно и то же свойство.

`v-model` же работает потому что в свойство val записываются сначала данные от пользователя, потом ваши. Но это не решение: использовав `v-model` вы больше не сможете гарантировать что в свойстве `val` находится именно то что вам нужно.

Правильно в таком случае работать с элементом напрямую.

---

PS если вы пытаетесь таким хитрым образом сделать фильтрацию вводимых символов - лучше блокируйте нежелательные символы через `preventDefault()` а не через присвоение value. Присвоение value сбрасывает текущее положение текстового курсора.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта:

A. Использовать `v-model` для двустороннего связывания:

```
<input v-model="val" v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)">
```

B. Создать ссылку на `input`:

```
<input ref="input" v-bind:value="val" v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)">
```

и в методе `updateValue` явно обновлять значение поля ввода:

```
this.$refs.input.value = this.val;
```

[Документация](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)